# facebook share IE problems

Tags: facebook

```
<a name="fb_share"></a> 
        <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
                type="text/javascript">
        </script>
```

i am using above code for implementing facebook share in my website its working fine in firefox and chrome but in IE when i am clicking on share button it is creating two instances of one as a popup and another instance opens in the same tab i just want the popup are there any methods to prevent this

Answer (score 0):

It seems that facebook tries to solve some issues ( cross-domain, i believe ) by loading twice the page. 
You can prevent this behavior by specifying a channel url on init. Check [FB.init](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init)

Basically, instead of loading your page a second time, you specify an url to load instead.

```
FB.init({
     appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
     channelUrl  : 'http://example.com/channel.html'  // custom channel
   });
```

The only content needed in that html file is:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```